# Rails date properties won't save to MySQL database

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, datetime, activerecord

I have a rails application which is running MySQL in production and SQLite in development. In development mode everything is working fine, but in production datetime properties just won't get saved to the database (even the created_at and updated_at won't). The field is not `null`, but `0000-00-00 00:00:00`. How is this possible? I did some research but I can't fix it.

schema.rb:

```
# encoding: UTF-8
# This file is auto-generated from the current state of the database. Instead
# of editing this file, please use the migrations feature of Active Record to
# incrementally modify your database, and then regenerate this schema definition.
#
# Note that this schema.rb definition is the authoritative source for your
# database schema. If you need to create the application database on another
# system, you should be using db:schema:load, not running all the migrations
# from scratch. The latter is a flawed and unsustainable approach (the more migrations
# you'll amass, the slower it'll run and the greater likelihood for issues).
#
# It's strongly recommended to check this file into your version control system.

ActiveRecord::Schema.define(:version => 20130306100623) do

  create_table "announcements", :force => true do |t|
    t.string   "title"
    t.text     "text"
    t.integer  "user_id"
    t.datetime "created_at", :null => false
    t.datetime "updated_at", :null => false
  end

  create_table "delayed_jobs", :force => true do |t|
    t.integer  "priority",   :default => 0
    t.integer  "attempts",   :default => 0
    t.text     "handler"
    t.text     "last_error"
    t.datetime "run_at"
    t.datetime "locked_at"
    t.datetime "failed_at"
    t.string   "locked_by"
    t.string   "queue"
    t.datetime "created_at",                :null => false
    t.datetime "updated_at",                :null => false
  end

  add_index "delayed_jobs", ["priority", "run_at"], :name => "delayed_jobs_priority"

  create_table "document_categories", :force => true do |t|
    t.string   "title"
    t.datetime "created_at", :null => false
    t.datetime "updated_at", :null => false
  end

  create_table "documents", :force => true do |t|
    t.string   "file_file_name"
    t.string   "file_content_type"
    t.integer  "file_file_size"
    t.datetime "file_updated_at"
    t.datetime "created_at",        :null => false
    t.datetime "updated_at",        :null => false
    t.integer  "user_id"
    t.string   "title"
    t.text     "description"
    t.string   "ancestry"
    t.boolean  "folder"
  end

  add_index "documents", ["ancestry"], :name => "index_documents_on_ancestry"

  create_table "inventory_items", :force => true do |t|
    t.string   "object"
    t.datetime "created_at", :null => false
    t.datetime "updated_at", :null => false
  end

  create_table "reservation_items", :force => true do |t|
    t.integer  "reservation_id"
    t.integer  "inventory_item_id"
    t.datetime "created_at",        :null => false
    t.datetime "updated_at",        :null => false
  end

  create_table "reservations", :force => true do |t|
    t.integer  "user_id"
    t.datetime "created_at", :null => false
    t.datetime "updated_at", :null => false
    t.datetime "start_time"
    t.datetime "end_time"
  end

  create_table "users", :force => true do |t|
    t.string   "first_name"
    t.string   "insertion"
    t.string   "last_name"
    t.string   "telephone_prefix"
    t.string   "telephone_suffix"
    t.string   "address"
    t.string   "number"
    t.string   "postal_code"
    t.string   "city"
    t.date     "birthdate"
    t.string   "email",                  :default => "", :null => false
    t.string   "encrypted_password",     :default => "", :null => false
    t.string   "reset_password_token"
    t.datetime "reset_password_sent_at"
    t.datetime "remember_created_at"
    t.integer  "sign_in_count",          :default => 0
    t.datetime "current_sign_in_at"
    t.datetime "last_sign_in_at"
    t.string   "current_sign_in_ip"
    t.string   "last_sign_in_ip"
    t.datetime "created_at",                             :null => false
    t.datetime "updated_at",                             :null => false
    t.string   "telephone_mobile"
    t.integer  "admin"
    t.string   "avatar_file_name"
    t.string   "avatar_content_type"
    t.integer  "avatar_file_size"
    t.datetime "avatar_updated_at"
    t.string   "sex"
    t.string   "lovo_email"
  end

  add_index "users", ["email"], :name => "index_users_on_email", :unique => true
  add_index "users", ["reset_password_token"], :name => "index_users_on_reset_password_token", :unique => true

end
```

Thank a lot!

Comment: There doesn't look like any obvious problem with the schema.  How are you creating the Date/Time items to save in the schema?

Comment: With a migration, example: `t.timestamps` edit: Rails.env on the server outputs 'production'.

Comment: OK, if the database is being created and tables are working, it sounds like a connection / configuration issue.  Has the system ever worked?

Comment: No, this is the first deployment on the server. Is it possible that Rails uses the SQLite datetime format to write to the MySQL database? 
Because if I open `rails console` on the production server I have to specify `-production` with the `rails console` command. 
When I just type `rails console`, it takes the SQLite database as default.

Comment: I installed MySQL locally and I get the same behavior.

Comment: try running through some examples in the console.  `rails console production`.  Do you know how to create objects and save them in the console?